# Android Studio strings.xml: 'NBSP' suddenly appeared in my strings.xml files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, localizable.strings

I suddenly have the mention 'NBSP' in my strings.xml files, just before special characters (!, ?, ....)

[image]

These 'NBSP' do not appear in my app when I run it. Also, when I do a copy/paste, they are not copied.

I have hundreds of them in many languages. They are not found in Android Studio by CTRL+F. A mess to remove...

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to worry or do anything about them.

It's a [non-breaking space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) that renders as a space but prevents line breaks at that point.